# What causes: Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id ... is not valid

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have an Kafka Streams application which running with 2 stream threads, everything is work fine until my log shows me:

```
2023-10-03 13:29:21 INFO  FetchSessionHandler:381 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Node 3 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=415564603, epoch=2118): INVALID_FETCH_SESSION_EPOCH.
2023-10-03 13:47:20 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:839 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-consumer-ecc87bcc-0a71-4e97-b78e-73f1d1fe27b4 is not valid.
2023-10-03 13:47:20 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:706 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Group coordinator redo-kafka137:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2023-10-03 13:47:21 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:706 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Group coordinator redo-kafka137:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2023-10-03 13:47:28 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:654 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Discovered group coordinator redo-kafka137:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2023-10-03 13:47:28 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:654 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Discovered group coordinator redo-kafka137:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2023-10-03 13:47:34 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:839 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer-682965f9-4d0d-4e69-aa6d-4afa5443f6fe is not valid.
2023-10-03 13:47:34 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:839 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer-682965f9-4d0d-4e69-aa6d-4afa5443f6fe is not valid.
2023-10-03 13:47:40 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:706 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Group coordinator redo-kafka137:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2023-10-03 13:47:49 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:654 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Discovered group coordinator redo-kafka137:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2023-10-03 13:47:49 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:458 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Revoking previously assigned partitions [dbb_output_product_details_testing-0, dbb_output_checksum_testing-0]
2023-10-03 13:47:49 INFO  StreamThread:207 - stream-thread [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4] State transition from RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED
2023-10-03 13:47:41 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:458 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Revoking previously assigned partitions [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000015-repartition-0]
2023-10-03 13:47:52 INFO  KafkaStreams:256 - stream-client [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa] State transition from RUNNING to REBALANCING
2023-10-03 13:48:09 INFO  StreamThread:207 - stream-thread [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2] State transition from RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED
2023-10-03 13:48:55 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1031 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-restore-consumer, groupId=] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2023-10-03 13:48:57 INFO  StreamThread:324 - stream-thread [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2] partition revocation took 11545 ms.
    suspended active tasks: [1_0]
    suspended standby tasks: []
2023-10-03 13:49:10 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:486 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] (Re-)joining group
2023-10-03 13:51:49 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1031 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-restore-consumer, groupId=] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2023-10-03 13:55:57 INFO  StreamThread:324 - stream-thread [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4] partition revocation took 456902 ms.
    suspended active tasks: [0_0]
    suspended standby tasks: []
2023-10-03 13:55:57 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:486 - [Consumer clientId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] (Re-)joining group
2023-10-03 13:55:57 ERROR InternalTopicManager:213 - stream-thread [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing] Unexpected error during topic description for LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000015-repartition.
2023-10-03 13:55:57 INFO  StreamThread:207 - stream-thread [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
2023-10-03 13:55:57 INFO  StreamThread:1178 - stream-thread [LoyaltyPoint_Calculator_Task7_Testing-fa190eb3-6ed7-4669-b10d-b31626dceafa-StreamThread-2] Shutting down
```

Then my consumer group is turn to REBALANCING permanently, I don't know how to stop it.
[image: Consumer group of my kafka streams apps]

In the finish of my code, I have tried calling close() method from my KafkaStreams instance, but the stream thread isn't close and still there, I check it by kafka command[image: Command checking running member in consumer group]